# How to specify arbitrary monomial ordering in Macaulay2?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, macaulay2

Suppose you are given an arbitrary order such as $w>x>y>z>a$ order. You can do renaming so that it becomes lex or similar errorsome renaming things to satisfy some of the more typical monomial orderings such as lex, glex and grevlex [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.8.2/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_monomial_sporderings.html). Is there any way to specify an arbitrary monomial ordering in [Macaulay2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Weights](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.8.2/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/___Weights.html) option to specify a given ordering:

> i1 : R = QQ[w..z,a, MonomialOrder=>{Weights => {4,3,2,1,0}}];
>
> i2 : toString (a+z+y+x+w)^2
>
> o2  = w^2 + 2*w*x + x^2 + 2*w*y + 2*x*y + 2*w*z + y^2+2*x*z + 2*w*a +
>   2*y*z + 2*x*a + z^2+2*y*a + 2*z*a + a^2

If you want to produce a more or less arbitrary ordering, you can use `Weights` together with [random](http://file:///Applications/Macaulay2-1.8.2/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_random.html):

> i1 : R = QQ[w..z,a, MonomialOrder=>{Weights => for i in 0..4 list
>   random 20}];
>
> i2 : (options R).MonomialOrder
>
> o2 = {MonomialSize => 32           }
>
> {Weights => {14, 15, 12, 9, 1}}
>
> {GRevLex => {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}   }
>
> {Position => Up               }
>
> o2 : VerticalList
>
> i3 : toString (a+z+y+x+w)^2
>
> o3 =
>   x^2+2*w*x+w^2+2*x*y+2*w*y+y^2+2*x*z+2*w*z+2*y*z+z^2+2*x*a+2*w*a+2*y*a+2*z*a+a^2